# Application is unable to connect to database

Tags: sql-server, roundhouse

I have a development-environment (dev) on which I have my .Net-application running which contains a RoundHouse-project to keep the database up to date. The database is running on the same machine. There are no problems with dev.

I also have a test environment with the same application and also a copy of the database. To keep the database on the test-environment up to date I run the RoundHouse-project from dev using the connectionstring to the database on the test-environment. 
This always worked fine but for some reason when I now run RoundHouse with the connectionstring to the test database I get the following error: `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.`

Funny thing is that when I recreate the connectionstring using a .udl file using the same properties and credentials I am able to connect to the test-database.
Running the webapplication using that same connection results in the same error.
I have already checked all the settings in the SQL Server Configuration Manager and made sure `TCP/IP` and `Named Pipes` are enabled.

I can ping the server and can connect to it using Remote Desktop.

Comment: Can it be Firewall that filters out your application by name?

Comment: I have turned off the firewalls on the dev- and the test-environment, but still no luck.

Comment: What your connection string looks like?

Comment: The same one I use all the same and which the application on the test-environment is using and actually works: `Data Source=<server-name>;Initial Catalog=<databasename>; User ID=<userid>;Password=<Password>;Trusted_Connection=False`

Comment: I mean what your <server-name> looks like? Is this IP-address,port or it's a computer name, or an alias? And is the SQL Server instance default or named?

Comment: I have used both the IP address and the alias, the SQL Server instance is default

Comment: I could imagine that sometimes computer name cannot be resolved into IP, but if you tried IP-address I have no idea. Another caveat could be the named instance, but you said it's default...

Comment: And nothing has changed in the configuration on that end

Comment: That could be not the configuration change, but for example someone turned off sql server browser (so you could connect anymore even using a valid instance name) or it could be DNS server down and you could not resolve the name into IP

Comment: ...But I have no idea that is not a firewall in case of a valid connection string in case of the default instance...

Comment: Could be the rh.exe app needs to be allowed through your local firewall. You can test to see if this is it by shutting off your firewall temporarily, attempting the connection with rh.exe and if it still fails, it's probably something else.

Comment: I have had a similar issue and managed to narrow it down (in my case) to RoundhousE 1.0.2 being unable to connect to an alias, even a local alias. This is a backward step from RoundhousE 0.8.6.0 that I was previously using.